# How to sort file lines in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file

How can sort lines in a file according to data in it?
Say I have a file who looks like this:

```
1 23 54 89
2 65 23 77
9 89 67 90
8 78 93 11
3 74 99 32
```

And I want to sort it according to the first column like this:

```
1 23 54 89
2 65 23 77
3 74 99 32
8 78 93 11
9 89 67 90
```

It all has to be done in Bash.

Comment: The [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) command seems like a good candidate.

Comment: In this case it's easy, `sort` and that's it... In general the command `apropos`, with the `-a` option is your friend: try this at the `bash` prompt: **`apropos -a sort lines`** and read the output. At this point you have a **strong candidate** and you can read the man page **`man sort`** and if you feel it's a bit terse there are always `google` and `StackOverflow`

Comment: Gishhh, I guess that was quite a silly question. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: The question is underspecified. Can the first column contain numbers outside 0-9? The other columns sort of implies it can.

Comment: It also doesn't clarify what `It all has to be done in Bash.` means, if it means using only bash-builtins it should be closed as **Needs focus**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*[sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)* is your go to.

```
sort <your_file>
```

Comment: This is too terse for a Stack Overflow answer. Is it an external command? Is it an internal Bash command (builtins)? Does the weird syntax highlighter hint at it being a builtin (or is it just plain wrong as usual)?  Is it actually part of Bash? Does it presume to run on particular systems? Is [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) involved? Is there official documentation to back it up and for further reading/details that can be linked to. Etc., etc. etc.

Comment: cont' -  The question says sort on "the first column". Presumably it can contain more than the numbers 0-9, say 42 and 1812. What if there are leading spaces? What if there aren't leading spaces? Will it work as intended then (presuming it is numeric data)? What if there are leading zeros? Will it erroneously interpret those as octal numbers? Etc.

Comment: cont' - In order words, the space-separated data might be a central tenet (or a least for a more general, more robust solution even if the simple solution works on the example data).

Comment: cont' - Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26774987/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) command:

```
sort -n test.txt
```